# Select all from table1 and all from table 2 where there is no matching row in table 1

Tags: sql

Example

```
Table 1

W__ | F__ | C__ | Code
15__ 4___   35__  A0
5___ 1___   2___   A5
8___ 3___   7___   A1

Table 2

W__ | F__ | C__ | Code
15__  4___   35__   NULL
2___   3___ 6___   NULL

Desired output

15, 4, 35, A0
5, 1, 2, A5
8, 3, 7, A1
2, 3, 4, NULL
```

I want to select all rows from Table 1 and append with all rows from Table 2 that do not contain a matching W, F, and C column to anything in table 1. Any help is appreciated. The underscores are only there to make spacing consistent

Comment: output doesn't make sense, where are you get `2,3,4,null`

Comment: you're right. I meant 2,3,6, null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with UNION in conjuction with NOT EXISTS:

```
Select * from Table1
UNION ALL
Select * from Table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 
                                       WHERE Table1.w = Table2.w
                                            AND Table1.f = Table2.f
                                            AND Table1.c = Table2.c)
```

Comment: Edited to include "ALL" as you suggested.  What kind of error did you get with `UNION ALL` ?

Comment: Every time I post an answer with UNION - ALL I just get a message that it failed to post, even trying in this comment I got:  'An Error Occurred During Comment Submisssion'

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't seem to getting the null rows from the second table. Since someone tested and it worked, i'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong that I didn't mention.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT w,f,c,code
FROM [table 1]
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.w,t2.f,t2.c,t2.code
FROM [table 2] t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN [table 1] t1
ON t2.w = t1.w and t2.f = t1.f and t2.c = t1.c 
WHERE t1.code is null
```

Comment: did you check the explain plan on that?

Comment: The execution plan probably isn't the best, but it should get it done considering table1.code is not null for any row